# Pseudorandom Number Generator with slight bias

Tags: math, random, generator, number-theory

I've thought about this for a while to no avail...

How would one go about creating a pseudorandom number generator with a *slight* (we're talking only apparent after millions, maybe billions, of iterations/tests) bias towards a single number. So, for example, if our generator is producing numbers from 0,1,2,...,98,99 and we want the slight bias for 47.

I feel as though there should be a clever Number Theory kind of solution to this but I couldn't find anything. Curious to see what y'all think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any good random generator with uniform distribution.

If your subrange has length N, generate values in range `0..K*N+1` (not including right border). If result `R` is less than `K*N`, output `R mod N`, otherwise output preferred value.

In this case we have probability for all elements `p=K/(K*N+1)` and for preferred element probability `q = p + delta = K/(K*N+1) + 1/(K*N+1) = (K+1)/(K*N+1)`.

If you have N and some bias criteria, calculate K to provide close bias value.

If you need more precision, use random range `0..K*N+F` with corresponding formula corrections (this approach gives any needed rational value of bias).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to single out some number is to do it explicitly. So you may have two perfectly good random generators and use one of them to control whether you return output from the second one or the hard-coded value:

```
if(controlGeneator.generate01Float() < Eps) {
     return 42;
}
else {
    return mainGenerator.generateNextInRange()
}
```

The nice thing about this is that it works even if the target range is really whole 32-bit range or whatever. Also by changing `Eps` you can control bias.

The obvious drawback is that for this to work really good, `controlGeneator` and `mainGenerator` better to be absolutely independent which is kind of a tough job. One idea might be to use different seeds (like `seed` and `seed + 1`) to initialize them and then use different cycles such as in each call actually draw 2 random numbers from the `controlGeneator` and 3 from the `mainGenerator` instead of proportion `1:1`.

P.S. IANAL but cheating in a game of chances might be illegal.